# Run DBSCAN on trajectories

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to run DBSCAN (sklearn.cluster) on a dataset of trajectories. The dataset is an array of arrays (trajectories) of arrays (points)

dataset_test =

```
array([[[46.37017059, 30.954216  ],
    [46.39661026, 30.94524956],
    [46.46545792, 30.94379807],
    [46.47494888, 30.94352913],
    [46.53890991, 30.94241714],
    [46.54576111, 30.95412064]],

   [[46.3741684 , 30.96355057],
    [46.40998077, 30.94839096],
    [46.43452072, 30.94845963],
    [46.47270966, 30.94708061],
    [46.48934174, 30.94626999],
    [46.5067749 , 30.94859695]],

   [[46.02920151, 31.13430023],
    [46.08929825, 31.13030052],
    [46.21580124, 31.04080009],
    [46.3125    , 30.96290016],
    [46.40140152, 30.95050049],
    [46.47000122, 30.94930077]],

   ...,

   [[44.21621323, 36.12607193],
    [44.35692596, 37.2990303 ],
    [44.42433167, 37.44826889],
    [44.47311783, 37.58980179],
    [44.50473022, 37.72211075],
    [44.52869034, 37.83360672]],

   [[41.54032898, 31.87997246],
    [41.60663986, 31.83249092],
    [41.63148117, 31.81200027],
    [41.67761993, 31.77362061],
    [41.69719315, 31.75731087],
    [41.7834549 , 31.68216133]],

   [[46.3062439 , 30.72232246],
    [46.298069  , 30.74869919],
    [46.28075409, 30.79483032],
    [46.2546196 , 30.86957932],
    [46.24847794, 30.96400261],
    [46.25270081, 30.97114944]]])
```

I've defined a distance function.
When running

`from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
clustering = DBSCAN(eps=3, min_samples=2, metric=hsdf_distance).fit(dataset_test)`

I get the error:

> ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2

Any ideas?

Comment: DBSCAN expects an array with shape samples by dimensions. You are providing an array with shape paths by samples by dimensions. Are you trying to cluster points on the paths, or are you trying to cluster paths?

Comment: I'm trying to cluster paths.

Comment: From the data shown, your data has the shape as N,6,2, where N is 6 for the data shown above. For DBSCAN or any ML algorithm, the data should be in (N, D) where N is number of samples and D is the number of features. You might need to reshape your data according to your problem.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do this. Some trajectories (which I haven't included above) have a different number of points in them also which was ideally the next step here. I basically just need the algorithm to look at each path as a point.

Comment: Basically, you want to reshape your array with `np.reshape(data_set, (len(data_set), -1))`. However, this only works if the number of points on each path is the same.

Comment: Personally, I don't think that clustering in such a high-dimensional space will work very well or be very robust. I would think about ways to reduce the properties of each path to a few metrics. If you tell us, what kind of data this is and what exactly you would like to achieve in the end, maybe we can help you with this.

Comment: Each sample represents a path taken by a vehicle (giving off GIS signals) - so is essentially a multiline with in this case 6 points given by 6 lat lon pairs. In most cases these paths have a different number of points to describe them due to more/less frequent signals. So the dataset as a whole is N multilines - some with more points than others. The distance metric I'm using (Hausdorff) works for different numbers of points (whether it's a good metric for this case is a different question).

Comment: How do these paths differ? Why could you not, for example, simply take the start point, mid point, and end point (instead of using the whole path)?

Comment: They differ in many ways. Think trajectories of planes in the sky. Some may have same start and finish but different path (and different in different ways also), some different start point, some different end point, some both different. Reducing the data so that all paths have the same number of points is possible but ideally I'm looking to use all points and then find the best distance metric. I might need to use a custom DBSCAN algorithm but I thought it would be possible with sklearns.

Comment: If you were to reshape the array as I outlined above, you would be effectively converting your data to an array with dimensions paths by features, where each feature used to be an x or y coordinate but is now something abstract. You are then calculating distances in this new "feature space". To compute the distance between points, you generally need all coordinates of both points. Therefor the requirement that all your paths have the same number of samples is not a detail of the sklearn implementation but a general requirement.

Comment: The Hausdorff distance metric doesn't require both paths to have the same number of points. So given two paths, however many points I have for each one, I can come up with a number that signifies a distance between them. Theoretically, treating each path as a "point" and given this distance metric, I should be able to run a DBSCAN algorithm on the set, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be hitting limitations of the sklearn API.

However, since using the "pyfunc" approach to a custom distance metric is very slow anyway - and not scalable - you probably can just instead **use a distance matrix**. You will not benefit much from indexing anyway. Then it is often faster to produce a NxN distance matrix and use `distance="precomputed"`.

Alternatively, you could use a tool such as ELKI that does *not* impose any such restriction on the input data - it does not need to be numeric or an array.

In particular, using a precomputed distance Marie's is beneficial when you don't know the values of epsilon and minpts to use yet, because you can reuse it multiple times.

The obvious drawback of a distance matrix is the O(n²) runtime and memory requirements that can be typically be reduced for index-friendly data sets.

Comment: Thanks. The issue wasn't so much the distance metric function (although I have gone with a distance matrix in the end). The issue was the input, ie having arrays of points as input instead of points for example. Theoretically it shouldn't be an issue for the algorithm but I guess for the particular sklearn implementation it was (or I'm not using it correctly). It seems to have a check at the start which stops the algorithm when the dimensions of the input are bigger than 2. I've found code on this site for a DBSCAN algo which I customised a bit and it's now working.

Comment: Well, if you now use a distance matrix anyway, then I would consider rather using the sklearn version (which is well tested) instead of unverified code from a random post (these quite frequently are flawed, and people copy&paste these flaws again and again).

Comment: And then replace each input array (like the six above) with a 1D index that I can map back to array after clustering? I hadn't realised that was probably what you were suggesting in your first comment. That would work, thanks.